# Не могу подписать драйвер для windows 7 64 цифровой подписью

Tags: windows, драйвер, цифровая-подпись

Есть такой замечательный драйвер Firadisk, но так получилось что он не подписан цифровой подписью, и на Windows 7 64bit его можно использовать только при отключении проверки цифровой подписи. При этом на компьютере становится невозможно запускать некоторые сетевые игры (пример GTA5) античит ругается на выключение проверки цифровой подписи. Как можно подписать драйвер не покупая дорогущий сертификат на год?

Comment: А зачем тебе этот `Firadisk` нужен?

Comment: Я сделала так, чтобы у меня windows загружалась вся в ram, для этого использую Firadisk (драйвер виртуального диска) но многие игры при таком подходе у меня не запускаются из-за того, что отключена проверка цифровой подписи, и я даже поиграть не могу. Или может быть кто-то мог бы мне помочь, я была бы очень рада

Comment: 1. Винда своими штатными средствами выгружает куски себя в оперативу, которые часто вызываются. Это видно через "Диспетчер процессов". 2. Может появился повод купить SSD?

Comment: SSD намного медленнее, поэтому мне и хотелось сделать так, чтобы windows вместе со всеми программами была в оперативной памяти.

Comment: `SSD намного медленнее`, что за задачи такие, что кладут на лопатки какой-нить Самунг Эво + `1.` моего камента? Коллега тут подсказал про `asus rog ramdisk`.